# Why padding is not working in Chrome

Tags: css

[image]

This is working fine in IE8 but not working in Chrome. Please help me. I am using following code:

```
.sortpostdrpdwn{
       height:4px; 
       width:8px; 
       float:right;
       padding:15px 8px 5px 6px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. Can you provide a little more insight? What are you trying to do? Does it just ignore it, or do you get unexpected dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean it's "not working" ? I tested it to check for syntax error and it "works". Of course it's strange with this size and padding.

Comment: Please post some HTML and tell us what you expect to happen.

Comment: There is one image which i want to display and its displaying in bottom(in case of chrome but same thing working fine in IE). so i want to give some padding so that it display in mid in chrome as well as IE. So what to do?

Comment: can u post your image with html code

Comment: Please build a fiddle (http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net), and add the relevant HTML in your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify in detail, its not always persons are free to question your answer with insufficient code. Sorry if being rude.

Padding will have inside div effect. which is 8px & 4px in size with 15 8 5 6 that will lead to total of height:24 width:22px, so, that is how it was working fine in IE.

Thank you,

Comment: I am sure you mean that IE also considers applied padding as width. whereas other browsers don't. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/147587/68702

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes you are on the tip. :) IE is another area of Research :) what a waste of time for web developers in IE, reduces productivity by 50%